# ExtJS view model binding not working for date field

Tags: extjs, json.net

I am facing an issue with Date Field in ExtJs. My view model data does not bind to the date field correctly. From server, if my date gets rendered like this
"2010-07-13T01:02:10.000Z" it binds correctly. But if it gets rendered like "2010-07-13T01:02:10", it does not bind correctly to the date field.

Is there something we need to do to bind the data to date field? I cannot post the actual code but I tried creating a small sample but in that both formats are not binding correctly. But if i specify '2010-07-13', it binds correctly.

ExtJS Version 6.0.1.250

```
Ext.define('Plus.view.MainM', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main',
    data: {
        StartDate: '2010-07-13T01:15:20.000Z',
        Name: 'Kapil'
    }
});

Ext.define('Plus.view.MainV', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        itemId: 'Name',
        bind: '{Name}',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        itemId: 'StartDate',
        width: 105,
        bind: '{StartDate}'
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Plus',
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    autoCreateViewport: 'MainV',
    launch: function() {

    }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not create a date object?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you mean use `StartDate: new Date('2010-07-13T01:15:20.000Z')`. It seems to work although for my actual scenario dates are getting rendered from the server using Newtonsoft Json library. I will need to check that out though but any other suggestions.

Comment: Without try but `altFormats: 'c'` doesn't work? `{xtype: 'datefield', altFormats: 'c'}`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work.